# How could I combine bar char and line graph using Plotly in R?

Tags: r, graph, plotly

I have two `data.frame` as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  week = c(rep(1, times = 3), rep(2, times = 3)),
  cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 2),
  count = round(runif(6, 1, 10))
)
```

And

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  week = c(rep(1, times = 2), rep(2, times = 2)),
  cat = rep(c("E", "F"), times = 2),
  count = round(runif(4, 1, 10))
)
```

I want to combine the bar chart create based of `df1` and line graph created based on `df2` i.e. I want to combine two plotly (fig1 and fig2) in one. Like the first figure of [link](https://plotly.com/r/graphing-multiple-chart-types/).

```
fig1 <- df1 %>%
  plotly::plot_ly(x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "bar", split = ~cat)

fig2 <- df2 %>%
  plotly::plot_ly(x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", split = ~cat)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach using `add_trace()` with your second dataframe:

```
library(plotly)
#Data
df1 <- data.frame(
  week = c(rep(1, times = 3), rep(2, times = 3)),
  cat = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 2),
  count = round(runif(6, 1, 10))
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  week = c(rep(1, times = 2), rep(2, times = 2)),
  cat = rep(c("E", "F"), times = 2),
  count = round(runif(4, 1, 10))
)
#Plot
plotly::plot_ly(df1,x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "bar", split = ~cat) %>%
  add_trace(data = df2,x = ~week, y = ~count, type = "scatter", 
            mode = "lines", split = ~cat,yaxis = 'y2') %>%
  layout(title = 'Title',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'var1', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y",
                       title = 'var2', showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

You can further customize the plot in the `layout()` option.

Comment: Is it possible to add specific colors to the different categories? I was trying `colors` command like `colors  = c( A = "red", B = "blue", c = "green")` similarly for line plot but I am getting error.

Comment: @PAULR67 It is better if you make that kind of changes in layout or inside each of the traces. The `add_trace()` function also allows for colors.

Comment: I was giving the argument inside trace only. Still I was getting error. I also tried `line = list( color())` still not getting actual output.

Comment: @PAULR67 Try saving the colors in a new dataframe and use `color=df$Var`.

Comment: Just tried. Coloring for bar chart is coming perfectly but not for line chart.